# How to create new dataframe with pandas based on columns of other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns 'A', 'B', 'C' and I want to create a new dataframe that has columns named 'X', 'Y', 'Z' which will respectively be column 'A' divided by column 'B', 'B' by 'C' and 'A' by 'C'. Also, I want to keep the same index. I have tried the following

```
new_df = old_df['A'] / old_df['B']
```

However, I don't know how to add the other columns I want.

Comment: `old_df['X']  = old_df['A'] / old_df['B']`

Comment: I understand how to add these new columns to the existing dataframe, but I want to create a new dataframe for these columns.

Comment: just declare that variable with ```new_df = pandas.DataFrame()``` and then you can ```new_df['X'] = old_df['A']/old_df['B']```

Comment: I really thought I tried this already but it's working, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
new_df['X'] = df['A'] / df['B']
new_df['Y'] = df['B'] / df['C']
new_df['Z'] = df['A'] / df['C']
print(new_df)

          X         Y         Z
0  0.227273  0.647059  0.147059
1  1.600000  0.833333  1.333333
2  0.800000  1.666667  1.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [pandas.DataFrame.div](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) which allows you use fill_values. For instance:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X','Y','Z'])
new_df['X'] = old_df['A'].div(old_df['B'], fill_value=-9999)
```